# spring4 boot addResourceHandlers not resolving the added resources

Tags: java, spring

My freemarker files could not load a newly added resources in linux server.

I'm using Resource helper below code

```
public class ResourceHelper {
    @Autowired
    private ResourceUrlProvider resourceUrlProvider;

    public CharSequence src(String path) {
        String url = CONTEXT_PATH + this.resourceUrlProvider.getForLookupPath(path);
        return url;
    }
}
```

and below is freemarker template.

```
<script src="${helper.src('/js/plugin/first.js')}" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="${helper.src('/js/plugin/second.js')}" charset="utf-8"></script> 
<script src="${helper.src('/js/plugin/NewPlugin.js')}" charset="utf-8"></script> -- Newly added js
```

The NewPlugin.js were added in same directory.

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    ResourceResolver resolver = new VersionResourceResolver()
            .addContentVersionStrategy("/**");

    registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/resources")
            .setCachePeriod(getCacheTime())
            .addResolver(resolver)
            .addTransformer(new CssLinkResourceTransformer());
}
```

Directory structure is below.

```
main
--java
--resources
--js
----plugin
-------first.js
-------second.js
-------NewPlugin.js -- New one
```

I am developing on windows. In Local testing, every resource was loaded fine. but could not load a 'NewPlugin.js' on linux server with nginx.

I guessed a server configure had different from a local on window.

but no different setting.

Comment: Did you get any errors on the Linux server? What were they?

Comment: @AleksanderLidtke getting no errors. just resourceUrlProvider.getForLookupPath(path) returns null.